# Django reverse resolving to wrong URL

Tags: django

Using Django 1.6, when there is a Http404, how come the url is resolving to `cci_update` instead of `manual_entry_cci`?

```
    url(r'^cci/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.CCiDetail.as_view(), name='cci_detail'),
    url(r'^cci/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', views.CCiLimitUpdateView.as_view(), name='cci_update'),
    url(r'^cci/search/$', views.CCiSearch.as_view(), name='cci_search'),
    url(r'^cci/manual_enter/(?P<cci_entry>\d+)/$', views.ManualDdiEnter.as_view(), 
        name='manual_entry_cci'),



class CCiDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = CCi

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        slug =  self.kwargs['pk']
        try:
            cci = super(CCiDetail, self).get_object(queryset)
            return cci
        except Http404:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('manual_entry_cci',
                kwargs={'cci_entry': slug}))







Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://10.14.44.19:8000/cci/454/
Django Version: 1.6.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:        
Reverse for 'cci_update' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cci/(?P<pk>\\d+)/update/$']
```

Comment: i'm not certain about this but are we allowed to return a HttpResponse object for the get_object method?

Answer (score 1):

This is strange:

```
 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cci/(?P<pk>\\d+)/update/$']
```

I guess your url config you show us is not used, but a different one. I guess django loads an old url config.

Comment: No, because if I mismatch the argument `cci_entry`, then it hits `manual_entry_cci` with failure.